# Get uri segment in index function of controller - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a url

www.xample.com/app/pay/11

where pay is my controller.
The controller is defined as

```
class Pay extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->model('users');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //How can I get 11 from uri ?
    }
}
```

Im not using any additional function here.Im using an index function.How could I get the value 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`_remap()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) to run the `index()` function for anything sent to this class.

```
class Pay extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->model('users');
    }

    function _remap($method, $params=array())
    {
        $methodToCall = method_exists($this, $method) ? $method : 'index';
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $methodToCall), $params);
    }

    function index($val)
    {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Now, when you go to `www.xample.com/app/pay/11`, `index()` will be called.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the URI Segment class of codeigniter..
it like `$this->uri->segment(n)`

In your case, you need to get the 3rd segment.

Hence, it will be-

```
echo $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: This gives a 404 error as there is not FUNCTION "11" in the class.Codeigniter treat the '11' as a function

Comment: load the url helper first.

Comment: i wanted to describe you more, but need to leave right now, hope my answer would prove helpful to you. just look in codeigniter user-guide, You can get everything there about codeigniter

Comment: No , I did.You didnt got what I have asked i guess

Comment: Helper class is loaded but still Im getting page not found error.Pay is my controller

Answer (score 1):

http://localhost/abc/sellers/YWRtaW4=

http://localhost/abc/sellers/follow/u/1

```
function _remap($method, $params=array())
    {
        $method_exists = method_exists($this, $method);
        $methodToCall = $method_exists ? $method : 'index';
        $this->$methodToCall($method_exists ? $params : $method);
    }


function index($username) {
        echo $username;
}

function follow($param){
   print_r($param);
}
```

Try to use this function..

Answer (score 0):

enable url helper in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or load url helper in desired controller or its method

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

and then use below in controller

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```