# Codeigniter routes for passing get parameter to index function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a url `www.mywebsite.com/store/123456`

where store is my controller class and I have a index function in it where Im getting the value after after store ,ie 123456.But im not able to achieve it.

As found online,I have tried adding this to routes `$route['store/(:any)'] = 'store/index';` also tried

```
$route['store/(:any)'] = 'store/index/$1';
```

but doesn't seem to work.Please help me out.

In controller index function is

```
public function index()
    {
        echo $this->uri->segment(1);
    }
```

But its not working.Pleae help

Comment: Did you try to add a param to your `index()` function? Like `public function index($id)` - and then use the `$id` in the code? Plus, what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: Its showing a page not found error,when i goto www.mywebsite.com/store/123456

Comment: Is it CodeIgniter's 404 error or its web server's one? In the first case the problem is inside your code, but in second you will have to check the `.htaccess` in the project root folder and add instructions to pass all subsequent requests to CI.

Comment: Im gettign codeigniters 404 error.SO its the prob in my code?

Comment: $route['store/(:any)'] = 'store/index/$1'; this is tyhe route i have given

Comment: Are yous sure it's codeigniter's 404 and not something like `The requested URL /store/123456 was not found on this server`? You don't even need to set-up a CI route yet for what you want to do (Assuming your controller name is indeed `store`)

Comment: This is yet another CodeIgniter index method error. Either use _remap or make a workaround with routes. Show us whole routes.php file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get uri segment in index function of controller - Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795710/get-uri-segment-in-index-function-of-controller-codeigniter)

Answer (score 4):

You are invoking `123456()` method instead of `index()` method therefore you get CI's 404.

The simplest way is to use this kind of route

```
$route['store/(:any)'] = 'store/index/$1';
```

AND in top of it add parameter to index function in your case

```
public function index($parameter)
{

    echo $this->uri->segment(2);
}
```

note that I changed **segment parameter** please see [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html).

---

using [_remap()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)

```
function _remap($parameter){

   $this->index($parameter);
}

function index($p) 
{
    echo $p; //shows 123456 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly:

segment(n) gives you the segments of your uri before the routing takes place

rsegment(n) gives you the segments of your uri after routing (if routing occurred or the same as segment if it didn't)

so for /store/123456 getting rerouted to /store/index/123456

```
segment(1) == rsegment(1) == 'store'
              rsegment(2) == 'index'
segment(2) == rsegment(3) == '123456'
```

Comment: No matter what segment she writes down she gets 404. Question is about 404.

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
$route['terms_and_conditions'] = 'SO_front/page/1';
```

controller :

```
public function page($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
```

Output :
1

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution for CI3...i would prefer laravel for advanced routing, orm,restapi, build in vuejs.

```
$route['store/(:any)'] = 'store/index/';

public function your index(){
    $parameter=$this->uri->segment(2);
    //use parameter for sql query.
}
```

Let say your route `$route[store/product/update/(:any)]` , then `$parameter=$this->uri->segment(4)`

Problem?. You will need to change entire file code if you plan to change the route name include view, controller, and custom route.